# Which version of XMLSec is available for SUSE 11 and 12?

Tags: linux, suse, xmlsec

We are using XMLSec 1.2.20 for Red Hat and CentOS.

Which version of XMLSec is available for SUSE 11 and 12? We can't find a suitable version of XMLSec for SUSE 11 and 12. We think there are versions of XMLSec for other versions of SUSE, but we want it specifically for SUSE 11 and 12.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you compile [xmlsec](https://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/) from sources? I have found suse to be missing many programs, we just compile them from sources. xmlsec page still hosts sources for [1.2.20](http://www.aleksey.com/xmlsec/download/xmlsec1-1.2.20.tar.gz) version.
Looking [here](https://software.opensuse.org/package/xmlsec1) SUSE SLE-12 has experimental 1.2.22
Found 1.2.18 for [opensuse 12.1 in packman](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/12.1/Extra/x86_64/).
Found 1.2.18 for [opensuse 11.4 in packman](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/11.4/Extra/x86_64/).
Found 1.2.17 for [opensuse 11.3 in packman](http://ftp.gwdg.de/pub/linux/misc/packman/suse/11.4/Extra/x86_64/).